# Web service only Access by My Android Application

Tags: android, web-services, web

I am using `asp.net` web service with `Android` application for `select` and `insert` the data from `MS-SQL Server`.

I just want to web service only access by my Android application.

Because, web service is hosted on my private server and data is very secure. I am not want anyone can call my web service.

Any solution?

Comment: not sure but append a value with url which will give access to only u

Answer (score 1):

Make request in the `POST` request and use extra field to check for sender's. In this field you could use any secret key !

Answer (score 0):

In your request, just put a SHA-1 key (e.g `SHA1(Hard_coded_password_in_app_and_WS, unique_ID_stored_in_preference_and_in_data__base)`)

In your WS, just check if this parameter is ok, and then answer. It's not the best security ever, but it's quite easy to set up, and it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to do this (in my opinion):

1. if your app has user account involved, you can simply use user session to authenticate or the social logins eg. facebook
2. post request, with a header of a hashed key,

good read: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/gmurray71/archive/2006/08/restricting_acc.html